# Tool for test/train automation

Tags: feature-extraction, training, automation

I need to test different datasets as well as different algorithm implementations. The current workflow looks like:

- Perform feature extraction from train set
- Train classifier on this features
- Feed this classifier to production code
- Run production code on a test set, feeding samples one by one
- Take results of production code and convert to the same format as test dataset
- Show statistics

How to automate this as much as possible? I currently use a bunch of bash/python scripts. I've looked through sklearn pipelines, but not sure they would give any benefit except for running functions in a line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit too much just for this use case, but I have good experience with [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/).

It is an Apache project and quite helpful to automate some stuff.

Otherwise there are a lot of commercial platform helping you. Just google for data science platform.